# mailto: subject= and body= support in email clients

Tags: html, email, mailto

Does anyone know if when sending a html newsletter what kind of support the major email clients have for the subject= and body= parts of the mailto tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behavior varies by both email client *and* source application. Here's a likely enough example from my own system, using **pjp**'s link.

```
<a href="mailto:me@somewhere.com?subject=Hello%20People">Send Mail</a>
```

- Mailto link followed within Outlook client successfully fills subject
- Mailto link followed in IE successfully fills subject for Outlook client
- Mailto link followed in Firefox *fails* for same Outlook client (subject text remains part of "TO" field)

I tried the same link in HTML emails read by gmail and Yahoo web clients.

- Gmail correctly opens a new message with desired subject
- Yahoo pre-fills the subject, but truncates at the space ("Hello" only)

That much variation on just one computer makes embedded mailto tricky to use. I bet that's why many email newsletters provide a "View as a web page" link in the header.

Comment: I wonder if support has improved somewhat in the 7 years since this answer... I'll provide any info I find if this has changed since then.

Comment: @FireSBurnsmuP From my recent experience building email templates with multiple banners and responsive design, the support and rendering variations between different email clients hasn't improved. Outlook being the most developer-unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine they've got quite good support for it.  BUT!! But mailto will be used to send and email FROM the client TO me@somewhere.com .  Thats definitely not you sending out a newsletter.

You'll have to send emails from the server, potentially in a background process.

EDIT:
Slight rethink.  Are you talking about you using an admin section with a link with multiple TO addresses that will then open an email client to send out your newsletter?  In which case, even though the major browsers probably do have decent support, you shouldn't rely on it out in the wild, since its not in the standard (I think), so they are not required to support it.

EDIT AGAIN:

[rfc 2368 info](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) in support of my previous edit