# AS3 : cannot fill subject and body in mailto

Tags: actionscript-3, mailto

I am currently programming using as3 and I want to fill subject and body of my mail using mailto.

I tried everything I've seen on Internet but nothing worked :(

This is my entire code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

function openMailClient(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var mail:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mailto:hi@hi.com?subject=hi&body=hi");
   navigateToURL(mail);
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openMailClient);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: This way will never work... explain in a better way your goal, you want to send an email with a compiled subject/body? what are you trying to achieve? Have you got a webservice where you can configure something?

Comment: When i click on my program it opens my mail. I just wanted the subject and body automatically filled.

Comment: It will open your mail because you have some installed program that recognise the `mailto:` and then opens the application... The filling capabilities depends on the application itself :)

Comment: i'm using outlook, do you know how i could make it work on it ? *-*

Comment: and thanks for the answer

Comment: I'm not really sure... your syntax seems correct... By the way can I ask you why are you trying to achieve this behavior?

Comment: I'm in an internship and i need to do it for my master *-*

Comment: @electo Your code looks fine. Try it in the browser, If it's not working there, so try to verify that your OS default email client is configured.

Comment: I'm maybe an idiot but how can i try it in the browser ?

Comment: @electo Just "open" the `mailto` url in your browser like any other url  : `mailto:hi@hi.com?subject=hi&body=hi`.

Comment: It shows an error saying that they can't open my email client but when i try it in my code it opens. And my default email client is outlook.

Comment: @electo What is your OS ? May be when you'v tested in your browser, the default email client ( the app which will open `mailto` ) is not set for that browser. To set the default email client for the whole OS, open IE, then go to **Internet Options** -> then **Programs** tab (the 5th) -> then **Set associations** ( I translated it from french ) ... If your AS code can open outlook, so what's the problem ?

Comment: (sorry i'm late) So i'm on windows i configured the default email client and it works now. What i'm trying to do it's to open outlook with the subject and body automatically filled, it worked when i opened it on the browser but when i try it with flash it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments provided, if your goal is to send an email you should do it in another and better way...

For example you could create a webservice (php script, java service, or other technology dedicated to sending the email, expose an URL which after receiving subject,body, etc will send the mail...)

Regarding your problem with outlook I only found this other Answer that can help you...

[mailto: subject= and body= support in email clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310714/mailto-subject-and-body-support-in-email-clients)

The behavior depends on the browser, OS, and other external factor...
The `?subject...&body` syntax is not standard and any browser/application treats it in a different way...

Comment: Yeah i know, but i can't do that my master said i can only do it on as3 without using php, java or anything else sorry x)

Comment: Ok, then the final results is variable and depends entirely on the OS and the Mail Application itself :)